# javascript static setter inheritance

Tags: javascript, class, oop, static

I want to create a javascript class with a setter on a specific field so that extended child classes can have validation when setting that field. Essentially this is what I have in mind:

```js
class Animal {
  static set genus(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'string') throw new Error('invalid genus')
  }
}

class Monkey extends Animal {
  static genus = 'Simia'
}

class Alligator extends Animal {
  static genus = 1 // I want this to error
}
```

I would expect `Alligator` class to throw an 'invalid genus' exception, but it appears that setters are not inherited, or at least not visible in child class constructors

Comment: To say it another way, when you declare a static property in a subclass, it will override the setter in the superclass, it won't use the setter to assign it.

Comment: apologies, I forgot the `set` keyword in the `Animal` class. I added that just now. I suppose you also answered my question if I had typed it correctly.